# What is the point of using delete on a non-member function?

Tags: c++, c++11

Excerpt from the Standard 20.12 [function.objects] :

```
template <class T> reference_wrapper<T> ref(T&) noexcept;
template <class T> reference_wrapper<const T> cref(const T&) noexcept;
template <class T> void ref(const T&&) = delete;
template <class T> void cref(const T&&) = delete;
```

I am used to seeing `=delete` in the context of member functions. The intention is to prohibit an operation that was supplied by the compiler. For example, to make a class non-copyable or non-movable.

In this context, however, the intention appears to be the documentation of the intent. Is this right? Are there any other cases where using a `=delete` on a non-member function is desirable, preferable or inevitable?

Comment: You can use it in all cases where you think a function takes a too large set of arguments. So you take the evil arguments and make a deleted function that only matches those, but better.  For example, you may want to prevent `f(int*)` from accepting `0` (to only accept `nullptr` for null pointers). So you can add a `f(int) = delete;` overload.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

There are two general reasons that I know of to explicitly `delete` free functions: to reject undesired implicit conversions, and to provide a better error experience for users.

---

#### Rejecting undesired implicit conversions

One useful feature of `const` is that temporaries can bind to references to `const`. So this works:

```
void foo(const int& );
foo(42); // ok
```

That temporary `42` is bound to the reference parameter of the function, and its lifetime is tied to that reference parameter.

Now, consider `std::cref()`.The goal is to pass through this `reference_wrapper` to somewhere, so we need the underlying reference to stay alive. If we just had this overload:

```
template <class T>
reference_wrapper<const T> cref(const T&) noexcept;
```

Then I could write `std::cref(42)`. That would work fine, I would get back a `std::reference_wrapper<const int>` - except it would be a dangling reference. There is no possible way for that code to ever work.

In an effort to fix that obvious bug, we have this overload as well:

```
template <class T> void cref(const T&&) = delete;
```

That is, we are explicitly deleting (or defining as deleted) an overloading taking any rvalue. Now, when doing overload resolution, this 2nd overload is preferred when I pass in an rvalue, and that overload is ill-formed, and the compiler informs us of our bug (silly me, I can't do `cref(42)`!) instead of me having to spend a few hours with gdb trying to figure out why I don't have an object.

Other examples in the standard library are:

- [`std::as_const()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/as_const)
- [`std::addressof()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/addressof)
- [`std::regex_match()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_match) and [`std::regex_search()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search) (#6 accepts lvalue strings, #7 rejects rvalue strings).

#### Better diagnostics for users

A different class of example might be to provide a better diagnostic for constrained functions. Let's say I have a function that is only meaningful for integral types:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, int> = 0>
void foo(T);
```

And I try to invoke it with a non-integral type:

```
foo(4.2); // error: no matching function
```

This fails, as desired. But the error you get isn't super meaningful. Especially if there's other overloads. With Concepts, this'll be better - hopefully, but not necessarily.

But if I add the converse explicitly deleted overload:

```
template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, int> = 0>
void foo(T);

template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_integral_v<T>, int> = 0>
void foo(T) = delete;

foo(4.2); // error: use of deleted function
```

This is more explicit and direct. Especially if the author of `foo` provides a comment indicating why this is important. Basically, this is still SFINAE friendly while also giving the benefit of a `static_assert` directly indicating failure (whereas if we just `static_assert`ed, we'd get a clearer message, but we'd lose SFINAE-friendliness).

Indeed, the motivation of [N4186](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4186.pdf) was to make that comment part of the code itself (though this proposal was rejected). The example in that paper was:

> ```
> template <typename T>
> enable_if_t<has_compatible_vector_size<simd_float, T>::value, simd_float>
> operator+(simd_float, T);
>
> template <typename T>
> enable_if_t<!has_compatible_vector_size<simd_float, T>::value, simd_float>
> operator+(simd_float, T) = delete;
> ```

An example in the standard library is [`std::make_unique()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/make_unique) for `make_unique<U[N]>`.