# Why delete a non-member function?

Tags: c++, function, c++17, delete-operator

This is about non-member functions. I do [understand this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function#Deleted_functions) as an implementation. But I have a bit of puzzlement with the logic behind?

```
     // why this?
     void do_not_use_this_ever ( void ) = delete ;
```

If I do not want a function to be used, why declare it and then delete it? Why not just:

```
     // why not this?
     // void do_not_use_this_ever ( void ) = delete ;
```

If `= delete` declares an intent, just a comment like above declares the same intent.

Can anyone think of a use-case where declaring a non-member function as deleted is better then not have it at all?

Update

Already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42332777/what-is-the-point-of-using-delete-on-a-non-member-function) . Although. Both answers use `std::cref` as an example. As @geza said in the comment to his answer, it would be rather beneficial to discuss other use cases as well.

Comment: A deleted function still is considered in overload resolution, which can be useful for disallowing certain overloads but not others. Maybe not for functions taking no arguments, but if arguments are taken, or for templated functions, this is really useful.

Comment: A non-member function in general, or a non-member function with a void parameter list?

Comment: Possibly to disable template functions for certain argument types

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki exactly. not just `std::cref`. A non-member function in general. Template or not. That's not discussed in any answer, AFAIK.

Comment: @ChefGladiator *exactly* what? I gave two options

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Deleting a non-member function can be useful to disable a function with certain parameters. For example, here is [std::cref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref):

```
template< class T >
std::reference_wrapper<const T> cref( const T& t ) noexcept;
template <class T>
void cref(const T&&) = delete;
```

`cref` is used to convert an object reference to `reference_wrapper`. This can be used for example with `std::bind`: `std::bind` parameters are copied into the resulting object. But with `cref`, it becomes just a reference. So, `cref` must not be used with temporary parameters.

If the second overload wasn't deleted, then for example, `cref(2)` would be a valid expression (as a temporary can be bound to a const reference). This is a problem, as `cref` would return a reference to an object which will be destroyed. To disallow this, we need to delete functions where `cref` is passed a temporary, and this is what the second deleted overload does.

Comment: valid example thanks ... it turns out `= delete` is used to limit the number of foot-guns, which are (for some) a C++ ISO committee logic, difficult to comprehend ...

Comment: @ChefGladiator: this is one use case. Too bad that this question got closed, because I'm curious about other use cases. I'm sure that there are more.

Comment: I agree  + I did not close this question. Indeed `std::cref` is used in both questions as an answer. As a use-case what I am interested in is why not "just use" `static_assert` inside, for example, `std::cref` to disallow const reference usage. static_assert can provide the explanation on false, as a second argument

Comment: @geza: Why are you sad this question got closed?  Any good answer here is also a good answer to the other question -- this way all the answers get collected in one place, which is far more convenient for everyone.

Comment: @BenVoigt: nothing serious, and I agree with you. The reason is that I'd like to have other example for non-member delete than `cref`. There must be some other, real-world example...

Comment: @geza: That would fit well on the older question, too.  Hopefully a bounty will attract one (or more).

Comment: @BenVoigt: a bounty is a good idea, thanks!

Comment: @geza: You might have noticed that Barry added some more examples and explanation to [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42333009/103167) and earned the bounty.